# How to pass system time to a variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the current POSIX time from the system clock using Haskell but get the following error:

```
    • No instance for (Show (IO POSIXTime))
        arising from the sixth field of ‘Block’ (type ‘IO POSIXTime’)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Show Block)
   |
16 |                    , nonce          :: Maybe Integer } deriving Show
   |                                                                 ^^^^
```

Here is the code for context:

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

data Transaction = Transaction { from  :: String
                               , to    :: String
                               , value :: Float } deriving Show

data Block = Block { version        :: Int
                   , index          :: Int
                   , transactions   :: [Transaction]
                   , prevBlockHash  :: String
                   , merkleRootHash :: String
                   , time           :: IO POSIXTime
                   , nonce          :: Maybe Integer } deriving Show

genesis :: Block
genesis = Block version index transactions prevBlockHash merkleRootHash time Nothing
    where version = 1
          index = 0
          transactions = []
          prevBlockHash = "000000000000000000000000000000000"
          merkleRootHash = ""
          time = getPOSIXTime
          nonce = Nothing
```

I've referenced a number of solutions to similar questions on stack overflow but haven't been able to get past the error for a few days.

Comment: Using `IO POSIXTime` as type does not make much sense: an `IO a` is *not* a value, it is in essence a *process* to retrieve an `a`.

Comment: Any time I change the type to something else I get a type error saying "Couldn't match expected type ‘Blah' with actual type ‘IO POSIXTime’. I'm slowly coming to understand the IO process, but can't understand what to do about it.

Comment: of course, you should make `genesis` an `IO Block`: a process that will create a `Block` and then first do `time <- getPOSIXTime`, and then construct it with `time`.

Comment: Thanks Willem - I'm going to deep dive into IO, this is weakness in my understanding.

Answer (score 7):

Let's begin by using a illustration of the of the type you have

```
data Block = Block { 
                     version        :: Int
                   -- removed a few field for illustrative purposes 
                   , time           :: IO POSIXTime
                   , nonce          :: Maybe Integer } deriving Show
```

As was commented `IO POSIXTime` is not really a `POSIXTime`, but a representation of the action of obtaining a `POSIXTime`. And let's change the type to an actual POSIXTime.

```
data Block = Block { 
                     version        :: Int
                   , time           :: POSIXTime
                   , nonce          :: Maybe Integer } deriving Show
```

Now we can adapt genesis to deal with our new Block:
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

```
data Block = Block { 
                     version        :: Int
                   , time           :: POSIXTime
                   , nonce          :: Maybe Integer } deriving Show


genesis :: IO Block
genesis = 
  do
     time <- getPOSIXTime
     let version = 1
     let nonce = Nothing
     return (Block version time nonce)

blockTimeAsUTCString :: Block -> String -- No need for IO
blockTimeAsUTCString (Block {time = p}) = show $ posixSecondsToUTCTime p

main :: IO ()
main = ioBlock >>= print >>
       ioBlock >>= putStrLn . blockTimeAsUTCString
       where ioBlock = genesis
```

Notice how we moved IO from inside Block to outside and how it plays well with the fact that an Haskell executable is always an `IO ()` and `blockTimeAsUTCString` shows how the record can be processed without relying on IO.

Comment: Thank you so much for spelling this out for me, it compiles. Are there any downsides to turning genesis into an IO Block? I'm still trying to understand the IO wrapper and monads.

Comment: The trade off is that you need to use the combinators that operate on IO to anything on it, like in `genesis >>= print`, the main ones are `>>=`, `=<<` and `<$>`, the first two are named bind and the latter is map. You search for them in https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E. And of course, the do-notation, which simply syntatic-sugar for these combinators.

Comment: @Nick: `IO` is *not* a wrapper, for `Maybe` there is a `Just` data constructor, but for `IO a`, you can see it as a *recipe* to construct an `a`, not an `a` somehow wrapped.

Comment: And it's not actually a trade off, because you'd need these combinators to use IO POSIXTime anyways.

Comment: @Nick, if the time is part of the block, then you need to work in `IO` to produce the block. But if there's nontrivial logic in building a block, you should generally separate that out into a pure function and call that function in the `IO`. Here, there's nothing really going on, so there's no point.

Comment: @dfeuer, Thank you for explaining - do you have an example you could point me towards? I would love to take a look.

Comment: @Nick let me know if my expanded answer has the example you were looking for.

Comment: Another example would be to write `genesisWithTime :: POSIXTime -> Block; genesisWithTime time = let { version = 1; nonce = Nothing } in Block version time nonce`. Then you could define `genesis = genesisWithTime <$> getPOSIXTime`. All the  logic about how to form the block once you have the time is now in pure code. In this case, that logic is to simple to bother separating, but in many real-life cases, there's a lot more pure stuff to calculate.

Comment: I am struggling because I have a weak understanding of IO. If I convert genesis to an IO block, the remainder of my code breaks in multiple places as the functions are implemented to take a Block. My understanding is that if my block is an IO Block this will cascade throughout my code (any new blocks added in this blockchain will also have to be IO blocks, and functions interacting them will have to take IO, etc.). In other implementations I've seen this does not appear to be the case. Is there a resource you would recommend for me to understand what is going on here?

Comment: can't you share the code? Or ask another question?

Comment: Anyways, let everything can operate on Block (without IO PosixTime, with regular PosixTime) and once you have an IO Block you use map over it.

Answer (score -4):

If you are really stuck with such type signature for `Block` I would go on implementing `Show (IO POSIXTIme)` :

```hs
instance Show (IO POSIXTime) where 
  show _ = "Time shower"
```

you might go and make more general `Show (IO a)` instance

```hs
instance Show (IO a) where 
  show _ = "I can't Show what is inside this IO monad"
```

Ultimately,
you can write your own `Show` instance  of the `Block` instead of deriving it:

```hs
instance Show Block where 
  show block = "Block " <> show (version block) <> " .... "
```

otherwise change `Block` type signature to be just `POSIXTime` not wrapped in `IO`?

Comment: The last suggestion is the only one that _might_ be worth considering; to write orphan `Show` instances for `IO` would be an extremely bad idea.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes, although `instance Unsatisfiable "Cannot show IO" => Show (IO a)` wouldn't be an unreasonable thing to stick in the base package. ;-)